# HTML Form POST is null

Tags: php, html, forms, post

so I'm trying to simply send one field of data from a form to a php file. Below is my form in a table. I also posted my php code. It keeps returning that $username is null. Ive tried post/get and it doesn't seem to matter.

HTML:

```xml
<form action='http://k9minecraft.tk/scripts/adduser.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='first'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='last'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type='text' id='email'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Minecraft Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='submit' value='Send'></td>
            <td><input type='reset' value='Reset'></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    echo $username;
    echo 'username is not null';
}
?>
```

Comment: try `print_r($_POST)`, and post it in your question

Comment: If this is what you were looking for I will add it in my question. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /hermes/waloraweb097/b516/moo.bondsolutionsnjcom/k9minecraft/scripts/adduser.php on line 3

Comment: you have syntax error, can you do it without syntax error ???

Comment: Not sure why this line is a syntax error though. $username = $_POST['user'];

Comment: put it before the first line. `print_r($_POST);die;`

Comment: Ok got you there. I get this output now, Array ( )

Comment: also add the name attribute to your first name, last name and email fields. You did not added any name to them.

Comment: Okay with that I'm still getting, Array ( )

Comment: are your php codes  in `adduser.php` file ?

Comment: I'm sorry Alireza, can you rephrase your question.

Comment: Yes my codes are in adduser.php? I modified it to: <?php
print_r($_POST);
 if(isset($_POST['user'])){
        $username = $_POST['user'];
  echo $username;
  echo 'username is not null';
  }
?>

Comment: @AlirezaFallah I have updated the question to contain the new code.

Comment: when I post the data in your server, I get this :  `Array ( [user] => something ) something username is not null` , I think your code is okay

Comment: did you figure this out? i'm baffled. it's connecting to database, but the values being posted on the input[type=email] are returning NULL in PHP instead of the user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working. You need to add some condition, that checks, if `$username` is posted or not.

Something like that:

```
if(count($_POST)){
    $username ='';
    if(isset($_POST['user'])){
        $username = $_POST['user'];
    if ($username==null || !$username)
         echo 'username is null';
     echo strlen($username);
     echo $username;
   }

 }
```

Comment: this just remove a notice error if post is empty, certainly not solving the problem

Comment: Gave this a shot, but no it didn't fix it.

Comment: what are you getting now

Comment: Array ( ) using the code suggested in the comments of my question. Using just your code, the results were no different than the original problem.

Comment: I have added another if inside code. secondly if you do print_r($_POST);  what it gives

Comment: Array ( ) is what print_r prints out.

Comment: I have checked this code with me it is working. Please can you try it now I have updated it. If you enter a value in form and press button does it still shows $_POST array as null and nothing prints out???

Comment: Aha! Victory. It is printing the length is 16 and the correect username. Wonder what I did wrong?

Comment: first always try to initialize the variables like ($username) on the top. 

secondly always check for variable being empty like empty($username) or !$username.

Comment: why is this the correct answer? See virmaior's answer!

Answer (score 10):

The issue is that all of your inputs have `id` but not `name`. The `id` are used by JavaScript. The `name` are used for sending form data.

Change it to be like this:

```html
<form action='http://k9minecraft.tk/scripts/adduser.php' method='POST'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='first' id='first'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='last' id='last'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='email' id='email'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Minecraft Name:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='user'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='submit' name='Send' value='Send'></td>
      <td><input type='reset' name='Rest' value='Reset'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Names have beem added and no different result sadly.

Comment: @Kyle did you ever figure this out? i'm having the same problem now. it worked the very first time, now it's posting a NULL value :/

Answer (score 2):

Try this to find out if the field is posted by the formular:

```
isset($_POST['user'])
```

I think `$username==null` will be true even if `$username` really is equal to an empty string.

Comment: Ok so I tried this line and it didn't print anything out. echo isset($_POST['user']);

Comment: seems like you figured it out. At least it is working for me, when i post the form to the script on your server. I'm getting: Array ( [user] => chris ) chrisusername is not null

Answer (score 0):

This is how people usually do it:

```
if(isset($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['user'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
}
```

Note: `== null` will not work with empty string. see [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qnbbXz).

You also need to add a name attribute for other input fields of yours.

Comment: yeah but that's not what i meant. i meant you can not detect if it was empty or it was not set using `==` without a php notice.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $msg = "";
     /* Validate post */
     if(isset($_POST['user'])==""){
      $msg .= "username is null";
     }
    /*End Validate*/
     if($msg==""){
      $user = $_POST['user'];
     }else{
       echo $msg;
     }
    }

?>
```