# HTML/PHP Newsletter form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am fairly new to PHP and I am trying to make an e-mail submission (newsletter) form work.
I have the following HTML form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="mail-handler.php" method="post">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">                       
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your email address.." />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
</form>
```

And for it, i have created a mail-handler.php file with the following code:

```
<?php 
$to = "horia.imperial@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$subject = "Form submission";
$subject2 = "You have just subscribed to the Plantsnap newsletter!";
$message =  $from . " just subscribed for your Newsletter" ;
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

//Headers
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">"; 
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "You have subscribed to our newsletter. Thank you, we will contact you shortly.";
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
// You cannot use header and echo together. It's one or the other.
} ?>
```

The issue: 
When I press the submit button, it sends an e-mail to my address, but I recieve the following e-mail:

> from: 
>   to: horia.imperial@gmail.com
>   date:   Thu, Mar 16, 2017 at 12:23 PM
>   subject:    Form submission
>   encryption: Standard (TLS) Learn more

As you can see, the from: field is empty, that means that the $from = $_POST['email'] returns NULL whatever I enter in the input field.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I have one more question:

How can I make the message from the form submission appear as a little tooltip under the form, instead of redirecting me to link/mail-handler.php and echo "You have subscribed to our newsletter. Thank you, we will contact you shortly."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't named your input field, you need `name=""` and not `id=""` - Turn on error reporting and you'd have gotten a error with "Undefined index"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Form POST is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450748/html-form-post-is-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inputfield needs a `name` attribute for it to be send with your form

`<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address.." />`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set `name` attribute.  Try this:

`<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email address.." />`

And just a small advice: If you only send the email addresses for yourself some address may be lost. Insert the emails into an `emails` database table like this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO emails (email, time) VALUES ($email, CURRENT TIME())");
```